# Aperture: during Import, keys to check/uncheck an image?

Tags: keyboard, aperture, import

In Aperture 3, at the beginning of the Import process, one can select/check or unselect/uncheck images one by one.

But it requires the mouse.

In the Viewer view, during that selection process, I can go to the next image easily using the keyboard, with the <kbd>-></kbd> key, but what is the way to uncheck an image using the keyboard?

(ie without having to click on the checkbox with the mouse)

**Edit**

Since I'm here, and in order not to create another question:

is there a way to have the Undo to work *only* on the current image, being viewed in preview?

(the default for multiple undoes, is to perform the undoes even on previously edited images (not shown during the undo) - very confusing/dangerous)

Comment: I guess it would be better to separate your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with keyboard only at the moment. For whatever reason, Apple decided to not use the default OS X behavior for toggling checkboxes (<kbd>Space</kbd>) in Aperture.

Answer (score 1):

What can you do is to select the photos you want to import by:

- click and dragging
- cmd + click to add one photo
- shift + click to select the range from the current selected.

Then click on any photo's checkbox, and all checkboxes will be checked as well.

Comment: Using *only* the keyboard?